# Error Class 'App\Model' not found on form submit

Tags: laravel, class

when I submit a form I got this error.

> "Class 'App\tariff' not found"

```php
$tariff = new tariff;
$tariff->pol = $request->pol;
$tariff->pod = $request->pod;
$tariff->size = $request->size;
```

Comment: when I submit a form I got this error class App\tariff is not found

Comment: If there is actually a `tariff` class somewhere, you need to import it.

Comment: import Tarif class by adding Use App\Tariff

Comment: But in your code, you have written `tariff` instead of `Tariff` note the upper case T

Comment: @Kavi Case matters with class names in Laravel. Be careful!

Comment: Not just in __Laravel__, it's matters in __php__

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Well, that depends on your autoloader. Laravel's (Composer) cares. A custom one doesn't necessarily have to.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
use App\Tariff
```

& access this